Local storage doesn't work on reload. Why?
I have a list of items that should be saved if they are open also an 'active' item that is currently previewed. Everything disappears on reload.

const Projects = () => {
    const [allProjectsOpen, setAllProjectsOpen] = useState(false);
    const [reactProjectsOpen, setReactProjectsOpen] = useState(false);
    const [angularProjectsOpen, setAngularProjectsOpen] = useState(false);
    const [openItems, setOpenItems] = useState([]);
    const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(null);


    const projectItemsRef = useRef([
        {
            name: '_photo_portfolio',
            icon: <RiJavascriptFill className="w-6 h-6 text-custom-blue" />,
            type: 'react',
            component: PhotoPortfolio,
        },
        {
            name: '_angul_it',
            icon: <FaAngular className="w-6 h-6 text-custom-purple" />,
            type: 'angular',
            component: AngulIt,
        },
        {
            name: '_unknown_project',
            icon: <RiJavascriptFill className="w-6 h-6 text-custom-blue" />,
            type: 'react',
            component: UnknownProject,
        },
    ]);



    // Load state from localStorage
    useEffect(() => {
        const storedOpenItemNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('openItemNames')) || [];
        const storedActiveItemName = localStorage.getItem('activeItemName');

        const storedOpenItems = projectItemsRef.current.filter(item => storedOpenItemNames.includes(item.name));
        setOpenItems(storedOpenItems);
        setActiveItem(storedActiveItemName || null);
    }, []);


    // Save state to localStorage
    useEffect(() => {
        // Save state to localStorage when openItems or activeItem changes
        const openItemNames = openItems.map(item => item.name);
        localStorage.setItem('openItemNames', JSON.stringify(openItemNames));
        localStorage.setItem('activeItemName', activeItem);
    }, [openItems, activeItem]);



    // Add item to openItems
    const addItem = (item) => {
        setOpenItems((prevItems) => {
            // Prevent adding duplicates
            if (prevItems.some(prevItem => prevItem.name === item.name)) {
                return prevItems;
            }
            return [...prevItems, item]; // Add item to the openItems array
        });
        setActiveItem(item.name); // Set the newly added item as active
    };


    // Remove item from openItems
    const removeItem = (itemName) => {
        setOpenItems((prevItems) => prevItems.filter((prevItem) => prevItem.name !== itemName));
        if (activeItem === itemName) {
            setActiveItem(null); // Reset active item if it's removed
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <ItemList
                    items={openItems}
                    activeItem={activeItem}
                    setActiveItem={setActiveItem}
                    removeItem={removeItem} />
                <div>
                    {ActiveComponent && <ActiveComponent />}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};



I'm trying to save this to local storage so on reload it would have the list and the active item open. I can see it saves the items and active item to local storage but on reload everything disappears.

Its probably because of your useEffect Hook.
You are telling useEffect to listen to changes in openItems and activeItem, so every time the value of these state-variables change, your data gets set to the localstorage. And with every time, I also mean when the default value is set.
const [openItems, setOpenItems] = useState([]);
const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(null);

So basically when your component loads for the first time after you "reload", an empty array is saved to the localstorage and that is why it looks like the values are disappearing.
A simple solution I often use to avoid "first-render"-problems is by using another state variable to check if it is the first render and block the function out if it is.
Something like this:
const [openItems, setOpenItems] = useState([]);
const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(null);

//First render check variable
const [firstRender, setFirstRender] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
if(firstRender){
    setFirstRender(false);
}else{
        // Save state to localStorage when openItems or activeItem changes
        const openItemNames = openItems.map(item => item.name);
        localStorage.setItem('openItemNames', JSON.stringify(openItemNames));
        localStorage.setItem('activeItemName', activeItem);
}
}, [openItems, activeItem]);

Maybe that can help. Simple but works.
